# How to calculate bearing force on a pulley?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I came across an article (crop of an image is attached)

[image]

As the belt is not in equilibrium an it is in motion how can we apply the condition of equilibrium to calculate the bearing force,as by a vector diagram shown in the image?

Answer (score 1):

That diagram is actually showing you the bearing force which causes the pulley to be in equilibrium.

Note that with the bearing force shown, the three vectors add up to $0$.  They are likely illustrating how you would calculate the bearing force which results in equilibrium.

Comment: how can we apply the condition of equilibrium as the belt is in motion not in equilibrium?

Comment: @YousufIthfi Equilibrium just requires the forces to balance, which means it wouldn't change it's velocity if it were in motion.

Comment: What, if It is accelerating (i mean the velocity of the belt at a point is increasing)?